# Solve the following differential equation : $\frac{d^3y}{dx^3}+y=3+e^{-x}+5e^{2x}.$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

Solve the following differential equation : $\frac{d^3y}{dx^3}+y=3+e^{-x}+5e^{2x}.$

My solution goes like this:

> Given, $\frac{d^3y}{dx^3}+y=3+e^{-x}+5e^{2x}$. We write this, as $(D^3+1)y=3+e^{-x}+5e^{2x}.$ We first, calculate the value of the complementary function, i.e general solution of the differential equation, $(D^3+1)y=0.$ The roots of $f(x)=x^3+1$ are :$-1,a_1=\frac12+\frac{\sqrt 3i}{2},a_2=\frac12-\frac{\sqrt 3i}{2}.$ Thus, the complementary function $CF=c_1e^{-x}+c_2e^{a_1x}+c_3e^{a_2x},$ where $c_1,c_2,c_3$ are arbitary constants. Now, we evaluate the particular integral $y$ of the original equation  $$\frac{d^3y}{dx^3}+y=3+e^{-x}+5e^{2x}$$
> i.e
> \begin{align}
> &y=\frac{1}{D^3+1}(3+e^{-x}+5e^{2x}) \\
> &\implies y=\frac{1}{D^3+1}(3)+\frac{1}{D^3+1}e^{-x}+5\frac{1}{D^3+1}(e^{2x}) \\
> &\implies y = 3+\frac{1}{D+1}(\frac{1}{D^2-D+1}e^{-x})+5\frac{e^{2x}}{9} \\
> &\implies y = 3+\frac{1}{D+1}\frac{e^{-x}}{3}+5\frac{e^{2x}}{9} \\
> &\implies y= 3+\frac{xe^{-x}}{3}+5\frac{e^{2x}}{9}.
> \end{align}
> Thus, the particular integral is, $$y= 3+\frac{xe^{-x}}{3}+5\frac{e^{2x}}{9}.$$ Now, the complete solution of the given equation $\frac{d^3y}{dx^3}+y=3+e^{-x}+5e^{2x}$ is : $$y_1=CF+y=c_1e^{-x}+c_2e^{a_1x}+c_3e^{a_2x}+3+\frac{xe^{-x}}{3}+5\frac{e^{2x}}{9}.$$

Is the above solution correct? If not, where is it going wrong ? Is the method, valid?

Comment: After the edit you solution looks perfect.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Thanks for your kind validations and clarifications!

Answer (score 1):

Your CF or null space solution is wrong.Do you see why? ( Hint:think about complex roots)

$y_{\text{complete}}=y_{\text{null}}+y_{\text{particular}}$

---

Auxiliary equation : $m^3+1=0$

Auxiliary roots:

$m=-1,\frac{1}{2}\pm\frac{\sqrt 3i}{2}$

$y_{\text{null}}=c_1e^{-x}+e^{\frac{x}{2}}(c_2 \sin(\frac{\sqrt{3}x}{2})+c_3\cos(\frac{\sqrt{3}x}{2}))$

---

You have calculated $y_{\text{particular}}$ correctly by the method of $D$ operator.

Let's compute it using the method of undermined coefficients.

Let $y_{p}=A+Bxe^{-x}+Ce^{2x}$

$y_{p}'=Be^{-x}-Bxe^{-x}+2Ce^{2x}$

$y_{p}''=-2Be^{-x}+Bxe^{-x}+4Ce^{2x}$

$y_{p}'''=3Be^{-x}-Bxe^{-x}+8Ce^{2x}$

---

$y_p'''+y_p=3+e^{-x}+5e^{2x}$

$A+3Be^{-x}+9Ce^{2x}=3+e^{-x}+5e^{2x}$

Equating coefficients: $A=3, B=\frac{1}{3}, C=\frac{5}{9}$

Hence $y_{\text{particular}}=\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3}xe^{-x}+\frac{5}{9}e^{2x}$

Note:After the edit your solution looks perfect to me.I also knew that you have made a typo.But my intention to write this answer is to provide you an easy alternative.

Comment: Can you please elaborate why my CF is wrong? 

Comment: $a_1$ and $a_2$ are complex conjugate.Solve again: $m^3+1=0$

Comment: The CF in question is correct. The roots $a_1,a_2,a_3$ of the characteristic equation are simple and hence CF should be $\sum c_ie^{a_ix} $.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh You haven't noticed carefully.That's correct. Two forms are equivalent. But I am talking about the values of $a_1$ and $a_2$, should be complex conjugate(should not be same!).

Comment: @SouravGhosh Ah, that's a typo! Is my solution correct, now?

Comment: @Franklin This is the result of overconfidence.BTW, it's now correct. You can also use undermined coefficients method, it's better than D operator as some times factorization and inversion of D operator becomes complicated.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Umm..I dont quite get you. What do you mean ? I am so sorry if you felt my behavior to be rude whatsoever.  But I think this is a clear miscommunication. I never asserted overconfidence, in my post or even tried doing it. But if you felt it that way, I am sorry. Also , a suggestion: Please edit your post, so that I can accept it!